# What is the fastest way to get Bandit Crests?

Tags: guild-wars-2

[Bandit Crests](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bandit_Crest) are a new "currency" added with the release of Living Story Season 2, Part 5: Echoes of the Past. They can be used to obtain skins, among other things. For the skins, it takes 1,000 crests for each piece.

What's the fastest way of obtaining a lot of Bandit Crests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farming the events in The Silverwastes is the fastest way I've found. As the events chain together back to back, you can get lots of bonus chests for completing these events and also some crests for failing some of the events.

So go find a fort and hang out there, helping dolyaks, defending the fort and also rebuilding walls. You can roam away from the fort to take on the marked veteran enemies which count as an event too.

As for the skins, you're actually better off earning them through bosses. If you complete the personal story you'll get one skin. After that the skin will drop again if you complete the map event of killing all 5 champion bosses within 4 minutes of each other.

I would recommend spending your crests on Bandit Lockpicks as when a player finds a chest using a shovel it is visible to all players. Each chest contains a champion loot bag, which will probably net you more money.

Comment: On a map where all of the players gathered at Amber Sandfall, we prolonged the "*Pact Assault Preparations Completed*" objective as long as possible and kept farming each others' Lost Bandit Chests. Even had the legendary spawn multiple times (once twice in a row within 30 seconds). Decent return farming chests.

Comment: A note to anyone that sees my comment: The chests at Amber were nerfed, last night.

Comment: Also, so far what I've seen, the bandit chest also has 5 crests in it, which is the cost of the key.